# Checksums - ISBN program

Tags: java, loops, object, isbn

This problem has me puzzled. I tried using a loop like this: Basically I tried to get the first digit from the input and do the formula but it doesn't seem to work. It looks so simple but I can't figure it out. Could you help me? Thanks.

```
public static int ISBN(String ninedigitNum) {
   number = 9;
   while (number > 0) {
   int nextDigit = ninedigitNum.substring(0,1);

   ...
}
```

> Checksums (Source: Princeton University). The International Standard
>   Book Number (ISBN) is a 10 digit code that uniquely specifies a book.
>   The rightmost digit is a checksum digit which can be uniquely
>   determined  from the other 9 digits from the condition that d1 + 2d2 +
>   3d3 + ... + 10d10 must be a multiple of 11 (here di denotes the ith
>   digit from the right). The checksum digit d1 can be any value from 0
>   to 10: the ISBN convention  is to use the value X to denote 10.
>   Example: the checksum digit corresponding to 020131452 is 5 since is
>   the only value of d1 between 0 and and 10 for which d1 + 2*2 + 3*5 +
>   4*4 + 5*1 + 6*3 + 7*1 + 8*0 + 9*2 + 10*0 is a multiple of 11. Create a
>   Java method ISBN() that takes a 9-digit integer as input, computes the
>   checksum, and returns the 10-digit ISBN number. Create 3 JUnit test
>   cases to test your method.

I got it, thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: You have to pick each integer starting from the last index of the string.

Comment: But how to get the 10 digit number in all? We're going to have to sum it up somehow but because every number is multiplied by a diffrent number it is hard to  use a loop it seems (d1 + 2d2 + 3d3 + ... + 10d10 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about it isn't working? Either way, I believe what you're missing is that you're continually getting the same substring, which will be the first number of the string: `int nextDigit = ninedigitNum.substring(0,1);`. In addition, you're going to want to use an `int`, not a `String`; you can technically convert from String to int if desired, but the problem itself calls for an int.

There are two ways to do this that jump to mind. I would do this by realizing that mod in powers of 10 will give you the respective digit of an integer, but the easier way is to convert to a char array and then access directly. Note that there's no error checking here; you'll have to add that yourself. In addition, there are a LOT of 'magic numbers' here: good code typically has very, very few. I would recommend learning more data structures before attempting problems like these; to be honest there's very few things you can do without at least arrays and linked lists.

```
char[] ISBN = ninedigitNum.toCharArray();

//Process each number
int total = 0;
for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
    int current_int = Integer.parseInt(ISBN[i]);
    total += current_int * (10 - i)
}

//Find value of d1
for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
    if(((total + i) % 11) == 0){
        total += i*100000000;
        break;
    }
}

return total;
```

In general: Use print outs with `System.out.println(x);` or use your compiler's debugger to see what's going on during processing.

Comment: I didn't really learn arrays yet, is there another way to do it? Thanks. Also the problem I've been having is that it is hard to process each int and save it somewhere because since it is a loop it would do the same thing. For example I would want the first number to be multiplied by 2. If I put that in teh loop wouldn't that multiply all the numbers by 2? Because the rest of the numbers needed to be multipled by 3, 4, .....9 Thanks!

Comment: If you're relatively strong with math, you can see how you can extract digits by using mod (`%`) values in the power of 10 -- x%10 = the lowest-order digit, x%100 = the next lowest-order digit, and so on. I'll edit in an example on the answer itself programmatically, but the important part of this is to think the problem through logically.

Regarding multiplication: that's the advantage of an array, you want to separate it out to separate numbers!

I'm also surprised you're doing this kind of problem without knowledge of arrays... arrays are probably _the_ most vital data construct to master.

Comment: Since the checksum digit is *the rightmost*, you need to multiply `total` with `10` and add `i`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Chasmo: In the problem description, it seems like the checksum digit is the _first_, for some reason; or at least, that's how I read it. Realistically though, you'd be right -- checksum digits go after the data, so you just need to move the digits to the left (bitwise left shift) and then add the checksum.

Answer (score 2):

So,
This is the piece of code that I wrote. I still think it could be made more efficient.

```
public class Problem3 {
    public static String ISBN(String x)
    {
       char[]temp = x.toCharArray();
       int counter = 2;
       int sum = 0;
       int j=0;
       for(int i=8;i>=0;i--)
       {
           sum+= counter*Integer.parseInt(""+temp[i]);
           counter+=1;
       }
       for(j=0;j<10;j++)
       {
           if((sum+j)%11==0)
           {
               break;
           }
       }
       return x+""+j;
    }
public static void main(String args[])    
{
   String a = "020131452"; 
   System.out.println(ISBN(a));

}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
public static int ISBN(String nineDigitNum){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<nineDigitNum.length(); i++){
        sum += Integer.parseInt(""+nineDigitNum.charAt(i))*(10-i);
    }
    return (sum%11);
}
```

Also I believe if the checksum is == to 10, it should return an X, so you could either change the return type and add an if statement somewhere, or just put the if statement outside wherever you are using this method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short one without loops that uses only `substring(), charAt() and length()`:

```
public static String ISBN(String nineDigits) {
    int chkD = 11 - checkDigit(nineDigits, 0);
    return nineDigits + ((chkD == 10) ? "X" : chkD);
}

public static int checkDigit(String nDsub, int chkD) {
    if (nDsub.length() == 0)
        return 0;
    chkD = ((nDsub.charAt(0) - '0') * (nDsub.length() + 1));
    return (chkD + checkDigit(nDsub.substring(1), chkD)) % 11;
}
```

Output:

```
> ISBN("123456789")
"123456789X"
> ISBN("123456780")
"1234567806"
```